# Necesito recuperar el valor de un select input de tipo hidden con Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, select, bootstrap-tags-input

Tengo este problema y espero me puedan ayudar. Tengo un select input dentro de un foreach en Laravel. La cosa es que en el input visible está la informacion para mostrar al usuario (nombre) y el ID para recuperarlo en el controlador e hice otro pero de tipo hidden para recuperar el precio del producto seleccionado (pagina de inventario). Tengo ya un codigo pero no me saca lo que necesito.

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('change', '#tamano', function(event) {    
    var x = $("[name='precio']").val(); //ESTE es el que necesito recuperar (input hidden)

    var s = $(this).find('select option:selected').val(); //aqui recibo el input visible
    alert(s);
  });
});
```

Quiero hacer algo como asi pero no logro encontrar como se hace:

```
 var x = $("[name='precio': selected]").val();
```

FORMULARIO

```
      <select class="browser-default custom-select" name="tamano" id="tamano">
        <option value="">Seleccione</option>
        @foreach ($tamanos as $tamano)
          <option value="{{ $tamano->id }}">{{ $tamano->nombre }}</option>
          <option value="{{ $tamano->precio }}" name="precio" id="precio" hidden>{{ $tamano->precio }}</option> //este valor necesito recuperar
        @endforeach
        <input id="precioPan" type="hidden" >
      </select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saludos te sugiero cambiar tu lógica un poco en tu dropdown/select, primero que nada te sugiero usar el atributo **data** un ejemplo de uso seria:

```
data-precio = "mi_valor"
```

este atributo se puede colocar donde desees en este caso en cada option de la siguiente manera:

```
 <select class="browser-default custom-select" name="tamano" id="tamano">
        <option value="">Seleccione</option>
        @foreach ($tamanos as $tamano)
          <option value="{{ $tamano->id }}" data-precio="{{$tamano->precio}}">{{ $tamano->nombre }}</option>
        @endforeach
        <input id="precioPan" type="hidden" >
 </select>
```

Finalmente podrías tener algo así:

```js
$("#tamano").change(function(event){
valor = this.value;
precio = $('option:selected', this).data('precio');
alert('Precio: '+precio);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="browser-default custom-select" name="tamano" id="tamano">
  <option value="" selected disabled>Seleccione</option>
  <option value="1" data-precio="10">Prod-1</option>
  <option value="2" data-precio="15">Prod-2</option>
  <option value="3" data-precio="20">Prod-3</option>
 </select>
```

Si te fijas uso Jquery con data obtengo el valor del **option** seleccionado. con esto me evito usar otros campos ocultos.

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias. No tenía idea de ese atributo "data" cada día se aprende algo nuevo. De nuevo gracias!! Me sirvió